# Exit Sub And Call another Sub

Tags: vba, excel, call

I have two subs, sub1 and sub2. I want to exit sub1 completely and start sub2 if a condition is satisfied. My attempt is (running from :

```
sub1
.
.
If x=y Then
    Exit Sub And Call sub2
End If
.
.
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

but you're so close!

```
sub1
.
.
If x=y Then
    Call sub2
    Exit Sub
End If
.
.
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, haven't had a chance to try yet, but will this exit sub1 before it runs sub2?

Comment: well, it exits sub1 when you say 'call sub2'. when it has finished sub2, it will return to sub1, but then immediately exits, so in effect, yes. if you wanted to get picky, you could put 'end' before 'end sub' in sub2, and it would kill all macros running and never return to sub1. but the end impact is the same, and this is probably tidier.

Comment: My sub2 ends with a timer which starts sub1 from the beginning again, so I need sub1 to be completely "dead" while sub2 is running, which is why I was asking whether the above will kill sub1 before it calls sub2. Maybe instead of just "Call sub2" I could put "Application.OnTime (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")), "sub2"", giving excel 5 seconds to exit sub and then run sub2?

Comment: but I believe instance 1 of sub1 will die as soon as sub2 is over, regardless of any timer. and an instance 2 would be created if there was any overlap... though i like your application.ontime solution.